# A CSS code Or Any code to put text (saved in other server) into blogspot blog..?

Tags: css, server-side, blogspot

I have a blog in blogspot.

Step (1). Whenever any visitor visit my blogspot blog through Google, the search search string is  tracked through a javascript and the search string is saved in another server (say serverX)

Step (2). Now, when another visitor (human/Google Bot/Any downloader/etc..) visits my blog, he/she should be able to see the search string (Saved in ServerX) in my blog (anywhere, be it content or at the bottom of the blog....it doesn't matter)

Well, I can code the javascript and can also write a php code to save the search string...
but i've absolutely NO idea how to do the step (2)
Please tell me how to do Step 2...

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: @Nok, Just so you know, CSS is NOT a programming language, it can only format text/pictures/elements and make it pretty, but it cannot "put code" or "extract texts" or anything like that. Your question implies that it can, and that makes it very confusing to decipher what you are asking for. I think you might get some better responses if you edit your question (and title).

Comment: Well, Thanks a lot for replying. 
I'm a total newbie in CSS. Ya, i know that CSS is client side.
But in blogspot, using CSS along with Layouts Data Tags, it seems like partially server side. I mean, the tags like <data:blog.title/> can fetch the blog title and outputs it from the server itself....

I'm sorry if i made u confused!
Actually, i'm totally new to css.

Comment: <data:blog.title/> is some sort of proprietary templating system that they have...doubt you could run your own custom PHP in its place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think blogspot gives you the ability to edit any of the server-side template files, does it? If so, then it's impossible to do this.

If you really need this feature, you would probably need to use WordPress (an installation on your own server, not the WordPress.com service, as then you would be in the same exact situation as you are with blogspot right now).

Comment: Yup: CSS isn’t a server-side language. It’s only run in the browser, and all it can do is change the appearance of the web page it’s applied to.

Comment: Firstly, thanks a lot for replying.

Well, they(blogspot) allow access to the CSS template. We can modify it. 
So, is there any CSS code/keyword/method that have the ability to import text/file/anything from the net into the template ???

Comment: You could use an external background-image, but that's about it. As the others stated, CSS isn't a server-side language, it's not really supposed to deal with content. If you really need something like this I still recommend you move to WP. WordPress is a really useful system to know anyways.

Comment: ya, i can understand that wordpress is a much better option for serious bloggers..
As of now, I'm still a beginner and would like to stick to blogspot. Moreover, according to SERP analysis [done by myself :-) ], i think blogspot ranks better than other blogs!

Anyways, one last question, do blogspot allow ANY server-side scripting???

Thank you once again :)

Comment: No they do not...I suppose you might be right about the SERP thing (since blogspot is owned by google after all), but the platform is still extremely limiting...I'm almost certain you can't do any server-side scripting with BlogSpot.

Learning how to bend WordPress to your will is very valuable, I urge you to at least give it a try and see if it will fit your needs. It's possible to export all your blog posts from blogspot to WordPress.

Comment: Thanks for your time, suggestion, help.... You guys have cleared my doubt :)

Thank You :)